# User behavior monitoring database

Tags: mysql, database-design

I've developed an iPhone app that allows users to send/receive files to/from a server.

At this point I wish to add a database to my server side application (sockets in c#) in order to keep track of the following:

1. personal card (name,age,email,etc...) - a user can (but isn't obligated) to fill one out
2. the number of files a user sent and received so far
3. app Stats which are sent every once in a while and contains info such as number of errors in the app, he's OS version etc...
4. the number of total files sent/received in the past hour (for all users)

each user has a unique 36 digit hex number "AF41-FB11-.....-FFFF"

The DB should provide the following answers: which users are "heavy users", how many files were exchanged in the past day/hour/month and is there a correlation between OS and number of errors.

Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with DB design, so I thought about the following:

1. a **users** table which will contain:

   uniqueUserID | Parsonal Card | Files Sent | Files Received
2. an **App stats** table (each user can have many records)

   uniqueUserID | number_of errors | OS_version  | .... | sumbission_date_time
3. a **general stats** table (new record added every hour)

   | total_files_received_in_the_last_hour | total_files_sent_in_the_last_hour | submission_date_time

My questions are:

1. performance-wise, does it make sense to collect and store data per user in side the server side application, and toss it all into the DB once an hour (e.g. open a connection, UPDATE fields/INSERT fields, close the connection) ? Or should I simply update each transaction (send/receive file) a user does every time he performs it?
2. Should I create a different primary key, other than the 36-digit id?
3. Does this design make sense??

I'm using mySQL 5.1, innoDB, the DBMS is on the same machine as the server-side app

Any insights will be helpful!

Comment: So if I was a heavy user do you think that I sign up for his card?

Comment: @EdHeal, I Suppose so yes, I don't see how that is relevant to the questions. Where are you trying to go with this?

Comment: @Danel - So lets get a card that is not mandatory to enable one to measure and check the use of the internet. Stalin would love that (along with other fascists)

Comment: @EdHeal Are you criticizing me for trying to improve user experience?

Comment: Please explain why measuring number of files downloaded will improve your users experience

Comment: There are several types of files a user can send receive. plus, each file can be sent to multiple users. If I know the ratio of files sent/received and their type, I will know which part of the UI to work on more (the one that is used more often). 
The user is well aware of all the info his app sends!

Comment: So tell me how this achieved your goal of having better performance by knowing the identify of the user? Better to use your efforts improving the performance of the web site for everybody.